# Add SupportMapFragment to a LinearLayout

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout

I need to add a SupportMapFragment created with AndroidStudio. The fragment activity that uses it works fine. It is showing a map with is marker on Sidney.
But I need to put that map on a Layout (i.e., a LinearLayout) to add buttons and interact with the map.

I create a class MapsActivity.java with its corresponding layout activity_maps.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />


    <fragment xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Being that: *public class MapsActivity extends **AppCompatActivity***, Inside the *MainActivity.onCreate()* I tried:

1)

```
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map, mapFragment).commit();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    GoogleMap mMap = mapFragment.getMap();
    // NOT GOOD: nMap is null.
```

2)

```
    FragmentManager manager = getChildFragmentManager();
    [...]
    // NOT GOOD: Cannot resolve method getChildFragmentManager.
```

3)

```
    GoogleMap mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    // NOT GOOD: nMap is null.
```

What can I try next?

Comment: check this out : https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/CameraDemoActivity.java

Comment: Where to find dependency for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this. Modify First one

> You are creating new `MapFragment` using 
>   `SupportMapFragment.newInstance();` rather getting from xml
>   mapFragment

```
FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) myFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    map = mapFragment.getMap();
```

Comment: Right, I corrected it, but still doesn't work: mapFragment is still Null
 `at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMap()' on a null object reference`

Comment: Found the other mistake.
Method was called before `setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);`

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

let your `Activity` implement `OnMapReadyCallback`. E.g.

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
```

in `onCreate`, after `setContentView`, you do

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

When `onMapReady` is invoked you can use `googleMap`

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
```

It can take a while before the `GoogleMap` object is ready for you to use, hence `getMapAsync`  and the `OnMapReadyCallback`

Answer (score 0):

I publish here the complete answer for who will be interested, I found it not so intuitive. This lets you add a map to your custom Layout.

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        GoogleMap mMap = mapFragment.getMap();

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-35, 152);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker near Sidney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }

}
```

The layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />


    <fragment xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you post an updated solution? ,getMap() has been deprecated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This way to show google map in your screen

```xml
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

```java
public class RouteFinderActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    GoogleMap map;
    Location location;
    Button btn_search_route;
    EditText et_source, et_destination;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_route_finder);
        btn_search_route = findViewById(R.id.btn_search_route);
        et_source = findViewById(R.id.et_source);
        et_destination = findViewById(R.id.et_destination);

        btn_search_route.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String source = et_source.getText().toString();
                String destination = et_destination.getText().toString();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(source)) {
                    et_source.setError("Enter Soruce point");
                } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(destination)) {
                    et_destination.setError("Enter Destination Point");
                } else {
                    String sendstring="http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" +
                            source +
                            "&daddr=" +
                            destination;
                    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            Uri.parse(sendstring));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }

        });

        ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;
        map.setMapType(1);
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));

            if (location != null) {
                //zoom
                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .zoom(17)
                        .target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))
                        .bearing(90)
                        .tilt(40)
                        .build();
                map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest

```xml
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="apikeymap" />
```